# iPhone ad hoc distribution as a team admin with team agent's certificate?

Tags: iphone

I'm a team admin (but not team agent) for our company's iPhone program on ADC. Can the Team Agent, who is a separate person, provide me a copy of the distribution provision profile file that I can use with XCode to create an ad-hoc build?

This is because the team agent person is not a technical person but they're the one who signed up for the program.

When I add the distribution profile to my XCode organize, I see an error for the profile:

> A valid signing identity matching
>   this profile could not be found in
>   your keychain

I have my own development certificate installed (developer_identity.cer) as well as
AppleWWDRCA.cer installed onto my KeyChain manager.

Would we have to change the person who is the Team Agent so it's my certificate that's used with the distribution provision file to make the ad-hoc build happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are missing is the key pair that was used to create the development certificate.  I've been through this exact scenario and what you need is for your team agent to export his/her private key to send it to you so that you can install it in keychain on your machine.

To do so they would need to start up Keychain Access.app, browse the certificates section of the app then they can right click on the private key and export it for you.  They can set a password on the exported private key so that it can only be installed by people that have the password.

Once that is done they send you the key and you install it into keychain on your development machine.  You will then be able to use the certificate(s) they generate with that key.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem. I suspected this was the issue, so I'm very glad to see your answer confirms my hunch.  Thank You!

Comment: paulthenerd, your answer saved my life today... I would like to say that it is very important to export the key that is in the CERTIFICATES section of Keychain Access.app and NOT on the section keys. Thank you!